# multiple child value check on Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In a ViewController I have to insert three  Name,Surname and Number. Then I have to check that all the 3 fields, relative to one "student/user" per once, are the same stored on Firebase db with the following  structure:
-\Students
--\Number
---\Name
---\Surname
In this way Number fields works as principal child, unique for every single "Student"
The code that works for the check only on the Number node is the following:

```
Database.database().reference().child("Students").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.hasChild (self.Number.text!) {
            print("Correct number")
        } else {
            print("The number does not exist")
        }
```

How can I do the same kind of check also on Name and Surname? I've tried with innested ifs and &&, but at this time I haven't solved a thing.
Thanks.